# Automapper not mapping navigation properties with Queryable Extensions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have two classes (simplified for example):

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid ProductId {get;set;}
    public Guid? ProviderId {get;set;}
    public Provider Provider {get;set;}
    public AssetType AssetType { get; set; }
    public Login Login { get; set; }
}

public class Provider
{
    public Guid ProviderId {get;set;}
    public string ProviderName {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Product> Product {get;set;}
}
```

The mappings look like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Product, Models.Product>()
.ForMember(m => m.Provider, opt => opt.Ignore())
.ReverseMap();

cfg.CreateMap<Provider, Models.Provider>()
.AfterMap((src, dest) =>
{
    foreach (var i in dest.Product)
        i.Provider = dest;
})
.ReverseMap();
```

And I have them mapped to identical classes for both the Entities and DTOs. And when I need to map them I do this:

```
 public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts(int LoginId)
 {
     return adapter.GetProducts(LoginId).ProjectTo<Product>();
 }
```

The issue is that the Provider object/navigation property is not coming through after the "ProjectTo". I can see it in the adapter, but once it hits "ProjectTo" it loses it.

I try to do it another way like this:

```
return adapter.GetProducts(LoginId).ToProductModelList();

public static List<Models.Product> ToProductModelList(this IQueryable<Data.Product> _products)
{
    var _list = new List<Models.Product>();
    foreach (var _product in _products)
    {
        var _modelProduct = Mapper.Map<Models.Product>(_product);
        _list.Add(_modelProduct);
    }
    return _list;
}
```

And it gives me the error:

```
Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
Provider -> Provider
ASG.Library.Data.Provider -> ASG.Library.Common.Models.Provider

Type Map configuration:
Provider -> Provider
ASG.Library.Data.Provider -> ASG.Library.Common.Models.Provider

Property:
Product
```

On this line:

```
  var _modelProduct = Mapper.Map<Models.Product>(_product);
```

So I'm guessing that "ProjectTo" doesn't work for Data.Provider => Models.Provider because of this error, but it just doesn't throw for that...

I am not sure what to do here. I have other objects or lists of objects in these classes, like `AssetType` and `Login`, that comes through just fine, but I can't figure out why this one is causing this error and I don't even know where to start.

I'm using Entity Framework 6. Automapper 6.1.1.0 with Automapper for EF6.

Comment: "*the Provider object/navigation property is not coming*" - because you've setup AM to do so with `.ForMember(m => m.Provider, opt => opt.Ignore())`

Comment: @IvanStoev The mapping right below that should add a provider to each product.

Comment: It will when mapping `Provider` query, but not when mapping `Product` query.

Comment: And of course AfterMap doesn't work with ProjectTo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be a recursive error. I can't have both a provider on a product and a list of products on a provider. Automapper can't map to infinity... so I just ignore the `List<Product>` on the provider and now it works.

EDIT:

You can use `MaxDepth` like this with `ProejctTo<>`:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Product, Models.Product>()
.ForMember(m => m.Provider, opt => opt.Ignore())
.MaxDepth(1)
.ReverseMap();

cfg.CreateMap<Provider, Models.Provider>()
.AfterMap((src, dest) =>
{
    foreach (var i in dest.Product)
        i.Provider = dest;
})
.MaxDepth(1)
.ReverseMap();
```

But this only really gets you a Provider off of a product or a list of Products off of a provider, what it doesn't do is get a list of products off of a provider off of a product.

✔ `Provider` => `List<Product>`

✔ `Product` => `Provider`

X `Product` => `Provider` => `List<Product>`

I haven't tried `PreserveReferences` without `ProjectTo<>`, but according to the AM guide it should be automatic with 6.1.0. I want to use `ProjectTo' anyway and the depth of 1 is fine with me.

Comment: Yes, you can :) See https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/5.0-Upgrade-Guide#circular-references.

Comment: Still get `The type Product' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query.` error, so this doesn't work. I tried `MaxDepth` and `PreserveReferences` in every way and every combination... still getting that error.

Comment: I take it you use ProjectTo. PreverveReferences doesn't help with that. MaxDepth can, but it's not always possible. Try to write the LINQ from entity to DTO by hand. If you can do it, it's an AM bug. Otherwise, it's not possible in this case.